# areaint in Matlab vs. areaPolygon or areapl in R

Tags: r, matlab, gis, area, polygons

I am getting two different sets of values when I try to calculate the polygon area in Matlab vs. R. In Matlab, I used areaint (with the reference ellipsoid set to WGS84). In R, I tried both geosphere::areaPolygon on lat-lon or splancs::areapl on grid-converted Euclidean coordinates. The R results agree with each other, but not with the Matlab calculation. The two sets are on average 25% different (Matlab lower). What am I missing?

Comment: Try the R-Sig-Geo mailing list, instead. Not sure you're going to get an answer here.

Comment: What happens if you try a simple polygon for which you know the area?

Comment: Thanks, cross-posted on R-Sig-Geo. [link](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/areaint-in-Matlab-vs-areaPolygon-or-areapl-in-R-td7581399.html)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Using the self-contained example from ?areaPolygon:

p <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
library(geosphere)
areaPolygon(p)
#result in m^2
[1] 2.12582e+14

Here is the parallel code in Matlab (requires Mapping Toolkit):

p=[-180 -20; -140 55; 10 0; -140 -60; -180 -20];
area=areaint(p(:,2),p(:,1),referenceEllipsoid('wgs84','km'))
%result in km^2
area = 2.524097207871018e+08

>>> The results are ~20% (~40e6 km^2) different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the result from Matlab came from an incorrectly formatted input matrix: areaint() requires (lat,lon), whereas the R input was correctly formatted as (lon,lat).  This holds true for any of the previously mentioned R functions.

See also:
http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=reply&node=7581419